# measureit alternative in firefox?

Tags: firefox-addon, measurement

I used to use an add-on for firefox called measureit. Now its not working because of firefox keeps updating all the time and the developer hasn't come out with a version of measure it that is supported by newer versions of firefox. Does anyone know a good pixel ruler add-on for FF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download the [web developer toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/). It has a ruler built in. Once you install it, it will appear in your menu bars in firefox. Click on miscellaneous, then click on display ruler.

You could also try searching "pixel ruler".

Answer (score 0):

Not a Firefox extension (it's a Windows app), but you can try [Ruler](https://ruler.codeplex.com/). It's a simple too that does what it says. You don't even need to install it, just click and use.

It can stay on top of other windows, you can drag the borders to resize and switch between vertical and horizontal rulers. You can even open multiple instances.

I had the same issue with MeasureIt, it stops working with some Firefox updates. I found Ruler and been happy with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since I upgraded Firefox Developer Edition there have been serious incompatibilities with my previous add-ons.

Measureit add-on is one of the extensions that are not up to date with the new browser.

I found this alternative that works just fine though not as good as Measure it. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/browser-ruler/

If you are on Firefox developer option click on the tools icons > choose to Get more tools > search for 'ruler' and add it.